# My Android Application's database won't work, firebase's database rules don't work very well

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i've been testing my application to see if the "Post" works, and i've notice that nothing worked when posting the image.
[This is the error I see in the LOGCAT when i try to post.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3uhM.png)

I also noticed that in the Firebase database > Rules > Monitor rules, that also there were shown that the the database won't work. [This is what i see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7fAy.png)

Firebase database > Rules > Edit Rules,

[image: This is the rules code.]

I've tried different things to resolv this problem:

- Changing the Firebase Database > Rules > Edit rules > Rules code, din't work,
- Replacing the old google-services.json file with a new one, din't work.

If you need some other informations about my application's code or about what i did, ask down here in the comments.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: 1) Please replace all screenshots of text with the actual textual content, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. That makes it easier for us to read the text, and use it when trying to reproduce your problem or answer it. 2) Security rules on their own do nothing yet. Please show the minimal code that reproduces the error, and make sure that in that code you show how it meets the requirements of your security rules (e.g. by logging the current user).

Answer (score 0):

The condition in `allow read, write: if "request.auth != null;"` should not be a string literal, but rather should be:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

So there are no quotes (`"`) around the condition here.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [requiring an authenticated user in your security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, I'm sorry for the banality of the error I made.